Rural man builds A-frame house in 1980s New York City, vandals burn it down
This house is completely out of place in early 1980s New York City and the man faces many hardships in finishing the construction.
It is burned down by a gang of criminals known to the builder as it nears completion.
The arsonists are caught in the act and then the cops let this fish-out-of-water country bumpkin punch the leader of this gang in the stomach.
I believe a native New York woman was a romantic interest for this outsider as well.

Could be "Dream House (1981)".
From this page, the synopsis:

Charley Gross is a vacationing Georgia construction worker who meets
  and falls for Manhattan's comely Director of Urban Renewal, Laura.
  Despite facing rejection, Gross sets out to build a dream house for
  the both of them in one of New York's ghetto neighborhoods.

Here's a promo pic from the movie:

There's not much information on the movie (apart from synopses), but there's a news article here.

that must be it - brilliant find
